# Flutter Firebase cloud_functions package throws error: INTERNAL

Tags: firebase, http, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

When trying to make a call to a Cloud Function I get a "CloudFunctionsException"

- The code of the exception is "INTERNAL
- The message is "Response is not valid JSON object."

[image]**Describe the bug**

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
 - My call from the application is

```dart
 HttpsCallable _getName;

 _getName = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'getName',);


 try {
      HttpsCallableResult resp = await _getName.call(<String, dynamic>{'name': name,});
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("${resp.data}")));
    } on CloudFunctionsException catch  (e) {
      showErrorMessage(context, 'Cloud functions exception with code: ${e.code}, and Details: ${e.details}, with message: ${e.message} ');
    } catch (e) {
      showErrorMessage(context, e.toString());
    }
```

- My Cloud Function is written as so:

```
exports.getName = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {
        "data" : "You hit the call at least!"
    };
});
```

**Expected behavior**
In my response, I should get back the data: "You hit the test call". Instead, I get the error

**Additional context**
When I make calls to the same function but with the HTTP package and receive it on the back end with "onRequest", it works.

```dart
  void _checkPersonsNameGET(String name)async{
    try {
      http.Response resp = await http.get(_cloudFunctionUrl,,  );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("${resp.body}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))));
    } catch (e) {
      showErrorMessage(context, e.toString());
    }
  }

  void _checkPersonsNamePOST(String name)async{
    try {
      http.Response resp = await http.post(_cloudFunctionUrl, body: { "name" : name } );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("${resp.body}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green))));
    } catch (e) {
      showErrorMessage(context, e.toString());
    }
  }
```

```
exports.getName = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const name = request.query.name || request.body.name;
    switch (name) {
        case 'Andrew':
            request.query.name ? response.send("Na he is the boi Q!") : response.send("Na he is the boi B!");
            break;

        case 'Brett':
            request.query.name ? response.send("Na just wierd! Q") : response.send("Na just wierd! B");
            break;

        case 'Eddie':
            request.query.name ? response.send("My brother but yeah! Q") : response.send("My brother but yeah! B");
            break;

        case 'James':
            request.query.name ? response.send("The biggest! Q") : response.send("The biggest! B");
            break;

        default:
            request.query.name ? response.send("Dunno who that is! Q") : response.send("Dunno who that is! B");
            break;
    }
});
```

**It's a mock application and can be seen here**
https://github.com/earyzhe/firebase_cloud_functions_play

Comment: When you see the INTERNAL, does it include a number? Let's say, does it look like this: INTERNAL(1)?  If so, What is the number shown?

Comment: Hey. There is no number. In the details, it says "null". I assume that is where the code should be. I added an image above. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I asked about the number because those kind of errors "INTERNAL" normally come with a number. If you ever get to any of these, here's those code protos' mapping https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/code.proto#L33

Now, in the error thrown do you see a "status" field? This is like the one at https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors#http_mapping

Comment: As you can see from the image above, there is no status in the thrown error. Infact if you look at the "CloudFunctionsException" class that is included in the Dart "cloud_functions" package, it does not have a status value. https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_functions/latest/cloud_functions/CloudFunctionsException-class.html

Comment: Looking further it is not mapped from the response in "https_callable.dart"  file.

Comment: Check the following question. They have a very similar behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662815/firebase-cloud-function-returns-internal-error

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cloud function was in a file that was not exported in the index file. Make sure your function is properly exported and has been deployed properly.